# Sorting within a collection using System.Dynamic.Linq.Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am wondering if anyone has any experience attempting to order on a Collection within a Collection using the System.Dynamic.Linq.Core NuGet package.

[System.Dynamic.Linq.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

Here is my example: I have a collection of Customers and each Customer has a collection of Orders and I want to sort the Customers based upon the recency of any order that they may have placed.  This is easy to do in SQL as you just flatten the data and order by that field.  Also the caveat that I don't know which column within the Orders collection they may want to sort on, which is why I want to use a  Dynamic library.  They could order by OrderTotal, OrderDate, etc..

Comment: You can Implement `IComparable` in your `Customer` class then compare the MAX order date of the two objects, (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If I have 200+ entities that I want to use this functionality for it seems like that approach will not scale.

Comment: If you are worried about scalability, Microsoft suggests using the `IComparer` Interface, perhaps this will be of help (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var criteriaName = "OrderDate";
var orderDir = "DESC";
var ans = data.Select($"new(CustomerName,Orders.OrderBy{(orderDir == "DESC" ? "Descending" : "")}({criteriaName}).First().{criteriaName} as Criteria)").OrderBy($"Criteria{" "+orderDir}").Take(10);
```

Comment: If that works that is exactly what I am looking for.  Wasn't sure the library would parse a Linq Expression

Comment: @ewahner Certain methods are understood by the parser.